# Bootstrap 3 grid column for jumbotron header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, less

I have a jumbotron at the top of my site, with a background image which resizes fine when I resize the browser window.

I have another background image that lays on top of the jumbotron background image. I have been setting different breakpoints for that overlaying image using position: relative; and passing the appropriate pixel amount to top, left, width and height styles.

The reason I do this, is because the overlaying image needs to decrease as the web browser size decreases, and the reason I use top and left is because I want to have the bottom of the overlaying image line up with the bottom of the jumbotron background image at that breakpoint.

I know if I set the overlaying image to use a .make-sm-column(5) and the appropriate offset, it may work, but I am having trouble lining the bottom of the overlaying image to the bottom of the jumbotron background image.

Example html:

```
<div id="jumbotron">
  <div id="jumbotron-man"></div>
</div>
```

The css just sets the background-image and position to relative, and for each breakpoint it sets the top, left, height, width of the image, I do not currently use .make-sm-column or offset for the overlay. There are other overlays and text divs on the jumbotron, but I thought just asking about this will give me push in the direction and allow me to apply the same to the other elements overlaying the jumbotron.

As seen in the image, you can see how I want it lined up
[image]

I feel like I am not taking advantage of bootstrap in this situation, any guidance is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you post your complete related code here or create a sample of the issue at jsfiddle.net help will be faster and more accurate.

Comment: @Arbel I am looking more for an example that an exact fix to my problem. I don't know how to position an element at the bottom of its parent with using twitter bootstrap to do that, that is why I use position:relative and set the top/left styles according to the current breakpoint.

Comment: There are some different ways, a common way is to set position:relative; on the parent and position:absolute; on the child, to position the child at the bottom set bottom:0; for the child.

Comment: @Arbel thats the push I needed, add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Glad to be of help to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some different ways, a common way is to set `position:relative;` on the parent and `position:absolute;` on the child, to position the child at the bottom set `bottom:0;` for the child.

So:

CSS:

```
#jumbotron {
    position: relative;
}

#jumbotron-man {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="jumbotron">
  <div id="jumbotron-man"></div>
</div>
```